# Adding custom button in activeadmin rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to add a custom button to my form in active admin. When this button click it will add a text field. Can somebody help me with my problem?

this is my banner.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Banner do
  # See permitted parameters documentation:
  # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
  #
  # permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
  #
  # or
  #
  # permit_params do
  #   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
  #   permitted << :other if resource.something?
  #   permitted
  # end

  menu label: "Main Banner", parent: "Banners"
  permit_params :tag, :image

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do 
      f.input :tag, label: "Banner name" 
      f.input :image, :as => :file

    end
    f.actions
  end

 controller do
    def create
       @clnt = HTTPClient.new
       @uri = 'http://healthy-options.jumpdigital.ph/bannerUpload'
       File.open(params[:banner][:image].path) do |file|
          @body = { 'image' => file, 'tag' => params[:banner][:tag] }
          @res = @clnt.post(@uri, @body)
      end

      redirect_to admin_banners_path
    end

    def update
      bannerid = params[:id]
      @clnt = HTTPClient.new
      @uri = 'http://healthy-options.jumpdigital.ph/bannerUpdate'

      begin
        image = File.open(params[:banner][:image].path)
      rescue

      end

      if !image.nil?

        @body = { 'bannerid' => bannerid, 'tag' => params[:banner][:tag], 'image' =>File.open(params[:banner][:image].path) }        
        @res = @clnt.post(@uri, @body)
      else
        @body = { 'bannerid' => bannerid, 'tag' => params[:banner][:tag]}        
        @res = @clnt.post(@uri, @body)

      end
      redirect_to admin_banner_path

    end

  end

end
```

In this file I want to add my custom button.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: hi @NatalieHedström, I edited my post. Tnx :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to do the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to use partial form :) @ChrisSimeone

Answer (score 0):

- I have Two param accepted and rejected.
- Then i define Two button for Accept and Reject and this two i'm used to 
  accept and reject.

  action_item :status, only: :show do 
  link_to 'Accept', admin_leave_application_path(id: params[:id], status: 'accepted')end

  action_item :status, only: :show do 
  link_to 'Reject', admin_leave_application_path(id: params[:id], 
  status: 'rejected')
  end
- Now i Am define my controller and easy to explain how to button add and work.

controller do

```
def show

  if params[:status].present? 
    leave_application = LeaveApplication.find_by(id: params[:id])
    leave_application.update(status: params[:status])
    redirect_to admin_leave_applications_path
  else
    super
  end
end
end
```